# How can I prove the following characterization : $\langle u-\pi_ku,w-\pi_ku\rangle\leq 0$?

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, inner-products

let K be a non-empty closed convex subspace of an hilbert H,  $$ \quad \forall u \in H \quad\exists \overline{u} \in K , ~~ \|u-\overline{u}\|= \min_{v ~\in K}\|u-v\| $$ $$ ~~  ( ~~ \|.\| ~~ : ~~ norm ~~ on ~~ H ~~ and ~~ \overline{u}= \pi_ku ~~ \text{ called the projection of u into K}~~).$$
How can i Prove the following characterization : $$\langle u-\pi_ku,w-\pi_ku\rangle\leq 0. $$
$$\forall w \in K,~~ \langle.,.\rangle ~~\text{ the scalar product in H}$$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: See the proof of $(1)\Leftrightarrow(2)$ in the first section of https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_projection_sur_un_convexe_ferm%C3%A9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to delete my answer because 1) it was link-only 2) it answered a no-effort question. I copied-pasted it as a comment.

Comment: Please @YOUSSEFED, can you un-accept my answer, so that I can delete it?